# When not to do eigendecomposition for repeated linear transformation

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Let's say we have a point p, e.g. `(1, 2, 3)` on which we want to apply a linear transformation N times. If the transformation is denoted by matrix A, then the final transformation would be given by `A^N . p`. Matrix multiplication being costly, I was assuming eigen-decomposition followed by  diagonalization would speed up the whole process. But to my surprise, this supposedly improved method is taking more time. What am I missing here?

```
import timeit

mysetup = '''
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power

EXP = 5     # no. of time linear transformation is applied
LT  = 10    # range from which numbers are picked at random for matrices and points.
N   = 100   # dimension of the vector space

A_init = np.random.randint(LT, size=(N, N))
A = (A_init + A_init.T)/2
p = np.random.randint(LT, size=N)

def run_sim_1():
    An = matrix_power(A, EXP)
    return An @ p

def run_sim_2(): 
    λ, V = LA.eig(A)
    Λ = np.diag(λ)
    Λ[np.diag_indices(N)] = λ ** EXP
    An = V @ Λ @ V.T
    return An @ p
'''

# code snippet whose execution time is to be measured 
# naive implementation
mycode_1 = '''run_sim_1()'''

print(timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup, stmt = mycode_1, number = 1000))
# time taken = 0.14894760597962886

# improved code snippet whose execution time is to be measured
# expecting this to take much less time. 
mycode_2 = '''run_sim_2()'''

# timeit statement 
print(timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup, stmt = mycode_2, number = 1000))
# time taken = 8.035318267997354
```

Comment: I think it would be even faster to compute (A^n) @ p by p1 = A@p ; p2 = A@p1 ... Instead of doing n-1 O(dim^3) matrix multiplies, and then a O(dim^2) matrix vector multiply, this would be doing n O(dim^2) matrix-vector multiplies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hard to answer authoritatively. Standard implementations of both [matrix multiplication and eigendecomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/a/62911/124276) are O(n^3), so there's no a priori reason to expect one to be faster than the other. And anecdotally, my experience is that eigendecomposition is generally much slower than a single matrix multiplication, so this result doesn't entirely surprise me.

Because the matrix power operation in this case involves *twenty* multiplications, I can see why you might expect it to be slower than eigendecomposition. But if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L662), this interesting tidbit shows up:

```
# Use binary decomposition to reduce the number of matrix multiplications.
# Here, we iterate over the bits of n, from LSB to MSB, raise `a` to
# increasing powers of 2, and multiply into the result as needed.
z = result = None
while n > 0:
    z = a if z is None else fmatmul(z, z)
    n, bit = divmod(n, 2)
    if bit:
        result = z if result is None else fmatmul(result, z)
```

So in fact, it's not really doing 20 multiplications! It's using a divide-and-conquer approach that reduces that number. After thinking through the algorithm, which is really quite elegant, I believe it will never do more than `2*log(p)` multiplications for a given power `p`. This maximum is reached when all the bits of `p` are one, i.e. when `p` is one less than a power of two.

The upshot is that although eigendecomposition might be faster in theory than repeated matrix multiplication, it carries constant overhead that makes it less efficient until `p` gets very large — maybe larger than any practical value.

I should add this: won't multiplying the vector directly be faster than raising the matrix to a power? Twenty vector multiplications would still be `O(n^2)`, no? But perhaps what you really want to do is perform this operation on 10k vectors, in which case the matrix power approach is clearly superior.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive treatment of the issue. I ran the benchmark for power p = 15 and 16. Time taken for both are not drastically different though.

Comment: @Bitswazsky indeed, that part of my analysis was flawed; the number of multiplications will always be `O(log(p))`. The difference between 15 and 16 could be up to 50%, but not more. So `matrix_power` is much more efficient than a naive iterative approach (`O(p)`) would be.

Answer (score 2):

Both `my_code_1` and `my_code_2` contain just a single `def` statement.  So your calls to `timeit` are only timing how long it takes to define the functions; the functions are never *called*.

Move the function *definitions* to the setup code, and replace the statements to be timed with just the call of the appropriate function, e.g.

```
mycode_1 = ''' 
run_sim_1()
'''
```

Then you should lower (by a lot) the value of `number` that you pass to `timeit`.  And then you'll have to fix `run_sim_2()` to perform the correct calculation:

```
def run_sim_2(): 
    λ, V = LA.eig(A)
    Λ = np.diag(λ)
    Λ[np.diag_indices(N)] = λ ** 20
    An = V @ Λ @ V.T
    return An @ p
```

Once you've made those changes, you'll still find that the `run_sim_1()` is faster.  See @senderle's answer for the likely reason.

Comment: I doubt that to be the case. All the tutorials for `timeit()` point me to the implementation I've used here. e.g. [this](https://www.guru99.com/timeit-python-examples.html) one or [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timeit-python-examples/) one.

Comment: The line `Λ[np.diag_indices(N)] = λ ** 20` would probably be more efficient than what I wrote, thanks for that. What would be the rationale behind reducing the value of `number`?

Comment: Read the [library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), especially [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer), which explains how `stmt` is interpreted.  If `stmt` is a *string*, it contains code to be executed.  The only executable statement in your example is a `def` statement, so the function is never called.  If, instead, `stmt` is a *callable object*, then `timeit` will time the call of the object.

Comment: If you don't believe me, try this: `timeit.timeit(stmt='def foo(): time.sleep(3)', setup='import time', number=5)`.  On my machine, it returns approximately 1.4e-6, *not* approximately 15.

Comment: Also note that I changed the line that computes `An` to `An = V @ Λ @ V.T`.

Comment: I think you're right on the timing issue, I'll update my question to reflect that. Thank you. I didn't get your last comment though. I don't see any change in the computation of An in your code.

Comment: In the expression for `An`, I changed `Λ.T` to `V.T`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206403/discussion-between-bitswazsky-and-warren-weckesser).